# ¿Por qué me aparece que mis variables están indefinidas?

Tags: php, mysqli

Estoy tratando de hacer un CRUD, voy en la parte de actualizar pero me encuentro con varios errores que no he podido resolver. A continuación mi codigo del index y el script de editar. Agradezco si me pueden decir el por qué de estos errores y explicarme.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<!--
To change this license header, choose License Headers in Project Properties.
To change this template file, choose Tools | Templates
and open the template in the editor.
-->

<?php
include 'editar.php';
$con = mysqli_connect("localhost", "root", "", "codigofacilito")or die("error");
?>

<html>
    <head>
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <title>Crud</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <form method="POST" action="index.php">
            <center>
                <label>Nombre:</label>
                <input type="text" name="nombre" placeholder="Escriba su nombre"><br/><br/> 
                <label>Contraseña:</label>
                <input type="password" name="pw" placeholder="Escriba su contraseña"><br/><br/>
                <input type="submit" name="insert" value="insertar datos">
            </center>
        </form>  
    </body>

    <?php
    if (isset($_POST['insert'])) {
        $usuario = $_POST['nombre'];
        $pw = $_POST['pw'];

        $insertar = "INSERT INTO codigof (nombre, pw) values('$usuario','$pw ')";
        $ejecutar = mysqli_query($con, $insertar)or die("error al conectarse");

        if ($ejecutar) {
            echo "<h3>datos insertados<h3>";
        }
    }
    ?>


    <table width="500" border="2" style="background-color: #F9F9F9">
        <tr>
            <th>nombre</th>
            <th>password</th>
            <th>editar</th>
            <th>borrar</th>


        </tr>

        <?php
        $consulta = "SELECT * FROM codigof";
        $ejecutar = mysqli_query($con, $consulta);



        while ($fila = mysqli_fetch_array($ejecutar)) {
            $i = 0;
            $id = $fila['id'];
            $nombre = $fila['nombre'];
            $password = $fila['pw'];

            $i++;
            ?>

            <tr align="center">
                <td><?php echo $nombre; ?></td>
                <td><?php echo $password; ?></td>
                <td> <a href="index.php?editar=<?php echo$id; ?>"</a>Editar</td>
                <td> <a href="index.php?borrar=<?php echo$id; ?>"</a>Eliminar</td>

            </tr>


        <?php } ?>
    </table>


    <?php
    if (isset($_GET['editar'])) {
        include("editar.php");
    }
    ?>

</html>
```

----------------------------------------editar.php------------------------------

```
<?php
if (isset($_GET['editar'])) {
    $editar_id = $_GET['editar'];
    $consulta = "select * from codigof where id='$editar_id";
    $ejecutar = mysqli_query($con, $consulta);
    $fila = mysqli_fetch_array($ejecutar);

    $nombre = $fila['nombre'];
    $pw = $fila = ['pw'];
}
?>

<br/>
<html>
    <head><head/>
    <tittle><tittle/>
        <body>
            <form method="POST" action="" value="">
                <input type="text" name="nombre" value=<?php echo $nombre ?>"><br/>
                       <input type="text name="pw" value="<?php echo $pw ?>"><br/>
                <input type="submit" name="actualizar" name="Actualizar Datos">
            </form>

            <?php
            If($_POST){
            $actualizar_nombre = $_POST['nombre'];
            $actualizar_pw = $_POST['pw'];

            $actualizar = "UPDATE codigof SET nombre='$actualizar_nombre', pw='$actualizar_pw' WHERE id=$editar_id";

            $ejecutar = mysqli_query($con, $actualizar);
            echo mysqli_error($con);


            if ($ejecutar) {
                echo "<script> alert('datos actualizados')</script>";
                echo "<script> window.open('index.php')</script>";
            }
            }
            ?>
        </body>


</html>
```

Comment: Qué errores tienes?  Es imposible adivinarlos

Comment: Qué errores tienes? Es imposible adivinarlos

Answer (score 1):

Tienes varios errores:

```
$consulta = "select * from codigof where id='$editar_id'";//Te faltaba un '

if($_POST){ // estaba en mayuscula el if
```

Otro error:

```
include 'editar.php';
$con = mysqli_connect("localhost", "root", "", "codigofacilito")or die("error");
```

Haces un include de editar.php antes de definir `$con` cuando usas esa variable en editar.php

Sin decirnos el error que te aparece no te puedo decir mas hasta que no lo pongas

Comment: Notice: Undefined variable: nombre in C:\xampp\htdocs\crudyoutube\editar.php on line 19

Comment: No estoy halando de `notice` sino de porque a el no le funciona, ni si quiera he probado el codigo @NetVicious simplemente le indico porque no le puede estar funcionando. Pero gracias por tu aportacion

Comment: No pasa nada @NetVicious

Comment: @andres_tam por favor, cada información adicional, añádela en la pregunta, editándola. Si la pones en los comentarios a una respuesta, otros usuarios pueden no verla.